# c# access all html nodes

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to access all nodes in a website. Here is my some codes.

```
string Url = "http://quickfind.kassad.in/profile/euw/exploit4/"; 
string text1 = "";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc;
web = new HtmlWeb();
doc = web.Load(Url);
text1 = doc.DocumentNode
           .SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"games\"]/div[2]/div[1]/strong/text()")[0]
           .InnerText;
```

This code does not work. I can access `games` node but I can't access their child nodes. I tried to access with `InnerHtml` but it doesn't contain game's child node. How can I access that nodes? And also I tried to access with `webbrowser.documenttext` but its same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source of the URL, it looks like `<div id="games"></div>` gets populated after the page has loaded.

It makes an additional call to: http://quickfind.kassad.in/ahnlab_hs_sys/euw/AcquisitionServiceGate/RGN.aspx

Comment: So i cant access child nodes. Thanks for answer.